# c++ struct does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt

I am defining a structure in a header file, and then setting its members in the corrosponding .cpp file. For doing this I am using a function that is supposed to create a (same) structure in its scope, and then return it. Something like this:

**in header:**

```
#include <things>
class GLWindow : public QGLWidget, public QGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GLWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWindow();

    //....
    struct Drawable
    {
        GLuint     vertexBuffer;
        GLuint     indexBuffer;
        int        faceCount;
        QMatrix4x4 transform;
    }cube;
    GLuint cubeTex;

    Drawable CreateDrawable(GLfloat* C_vertices, GLfloat* C_tex, GLfloat* C_normals, GLushort* C_facedata, int faces);
    //.....
};
```

**in cpp file:**

```
#include "glwindow.h"

Drawable GLWindow :: CreateDrawable(GLfloat *C_vertices, GLfloat *C_tex, GLfloat *C_normals, GLushort *C_facedata, int faces)
{
    int faceCount =faces;

    QMatrix4x4 Transform;
    Transform.setToIdentity();

    GLuint VB;
    /*Create vertexbuffer...*/

    GLuint IB;
    /*Create indexbuffer...*/

    Drawable drawable;
    drawable.faceCount = fCount;
    drawable.transform = Transform;
    drawable.vertexBuffer = VB;
    drawable.indexBuffer = IB;

    return drawable;
}

void GLWindow :: someOtherFunction()
{
    //.....
    cube = CreateDrawable(cube_vertices, cube_tex, cube_normals, cube_facedata, cube_face);
    //.....
}
```

I am getting an error stating that *'Drawable' does not name a type,* but I can't comprehend why I am getting this error, or what I can do to eliminate it.

Comment: Might be typo `CreateDrawable` returns `void` in your header declaration & `Drawable` in source

Comment: In your header file, shouldn't it be `Drawable CreateDrawable(...)` instead of `void CreateDrawable(...)`?

Comment: another.anon.coward and Treb Yes. Edited it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, I intend on doing it, but not right now. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to qualify `Drawable` in the cpp file:

```
GLWindow::Drawable GLWindow :: CreateDrawable(GLfloat *C_vertices, GLfloat *C_tex, GLfloat *C_normals, GLushort *C_facedata, int faces)
```

In the cpp file, outside the member methods, you're operating outside the class context. Inside the methods you can use `Drawable`, but outside (including return type), you need to use `GLWindow::Drawable`.

That's if you're actually returning a `Drawable` from the method, not a `void` - also an error.